# Handling arraylists created in a custom class (newbie confusion)

Tags: android, class, arraylist

Basically, I need to add items to the arraylist. Am I correct in using a separate class  (this is in part what I am practicing here) or is that a stupid idea because it is basically just an arraylist. I thought I would create a class because I want to randomise additions to it, etc. Alternately, since it is just an arraylist class, should I use "extends arraylist" or something similar??? Code examples most welcome. I am obviously missing some crucial programming theory here. Thank you.

*NOTE* I have removed what I think is unrelated code
I have a main:

```
public class cgame2 extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Integer> cToChooseFromImages; // clear image list

colourlist colourlistused = new colourlist();
colourlist userscolourlist = new colourlist();

....truncated....towards the end of my code I have......
colourlistused.randomaddnewitem();
```

And I have a class (called colourlist):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import android.util.Log;

public class colourlist {

private ArrayList<Integer> clist;

private int picked;

int imagetodisp;

public colourlist() {
}

public void randomaddnewitem() {
    Random randomtouse = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    picked = randomtouse.nextInt(3);
    clist.add(picked); // this is where the program crashes according to log info
}
public void addnewitem(int itemtoadd) {
    clist.add(itemtoadd);
}

.....etc.....
```

Comment: You have to initialize your clist ie., private ArrayList<Integer>clist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding functionality to ArrayList, the best way is just the way you have done it.

Create a member ArrayList of your class and create functions to extend the behavior. This is called Composition.
Contrast with Inheritance, or creating a subclass of ArrayList, which can create more problems by unnecessarily coupling your implementation to ArrayList.

Don't forget to initialize the list. The best way would be:

```
List<Integer> clist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Use the interface `List` to make your code more flexible if you choose to change the specific list implementation later.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a class for your array list isn't a bad idea, classes in and of themselves are data structures, and this will allow to manipulate the data easier. By having the array list in it's own class, you will be able to get it, set it, send it, alter it, etc, with ease. However, when it comes to creating classes, you generally want to create classes that could be considered objects. If you are a beginning programmer, I would recommend exploring and researching object oriented analysis and design, as that will help you determine what should and shouldn't be classes.

And, as others have pointed out, make sure you initialize your array list:

```
List<Integer> clist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

As for extending `ArrayList` vs. `List`, I would use `ArrayList` because 1. It has all the methods and functionality of `List` (because is is an implementation of `List`) and 2. It is backed by an array, which is what you are using. Just my preference, feel free to do some research and figure out what is going to work best for what you need; a `List` may be all you need, in which case, you should use that.

One other things I will point out, since it looks like you are creating a game, is that if you are going to pass and object, in your case and `ArrayList`, you are going to want to get familiar with the `Parcelable` interface. It is what will allow you to pass data from one activity to another. Here is a link that will get you started, along with a tutorial that might offer some insight to what is needed:

Tutorial for `Parceleable`:

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Developer Info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Best of luck!